# Adding on my command to services menu or adding keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, software, services, shortcut-menu

[OnMyCommand](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/on_my_command.html) allows commands to be added to the shortcut menu. Unfortunately, I can't add them to the services menu or add a keyboard shortcut for them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use Apple's automator and save the result as a service. If you select the right conext for the service it will appear in the right click menu. You can add shortcuts to services using System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts. Click somewhere to the right of the service name (near the right edge of the white box). A field appears and you can type a shortcut. This is not very intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get it to work with commands from "On my command" rather than having to create new commands in automator

Comment: Automator does everything you want, including shell script, applescript, shortcuts, services and contextual menu. Why use OMC?